# How to integrate users of PimcoreMember bundle with CoreShop?

Tags: pimcore, coreshop

My website use dachcom-digital/pimcore-members bundle for authorization. Now I'm going to add some ecommerce feature to my website, so i decided to use CoreShop. Is there any easy way to integrate users already registered in my website with CoreShop customers?

Comment: This is a question for the developer of CoreShop @dpfaffenbauer. Guess you should ask him directly or ask in https://talk.pimcore.org/